# for each loop iteration

Tags: c#, enumeration

Let us assume the code I use to iterate through a  node list

```
foreach(XmlNode nodeP in node.SelectNodes("Property"))
{
  propsList.Add(nodeP.Attributes["name"].Value, true);
}
```

in this case does the expression node.SelectNodes("Property") , get evaluated during each iteration of for each or once?

Comment: What language is this that you are working with?

Comment: I've edited the tags because this has nothing to do with XML specifically - it's just to do with how the foreach loop works. If anyone disagrees, feel free to revert.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Only once. The foreach statement is syntactic sugar for (in your case)...

```
{
    IEnumerator<XmlNode> enumerator = node.SelectNodes("Property").GetEnumerator();

    XmlNode nodeP;

    while(enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        nodeP = enumerator.Current;

        propsList.Add(nodeP.Attributes["name"].Value, true);
    }

    IDisposable disposable = enumerator as IDisposable;

    if(disposable != null) disposable.Dispose();
}
```

So the actual call to `SelectNodes()` only happens one time.

Comment: Hi,

In that case, which code is better of the two,

for(int i = 0; i < StudentArray.Length; studentArray++)
{

}

Comment: Hi, In that case, which code is better of the two, 
for(int i = 0; i < StudentArray.Length; studentArray++) 
{
  // do something 
 } 

of 

int count = StudentArray.Length;

for(int i = 0; i < count ; studentArray++) 
{
  // do something 
 }

Comment: I'm assuming you meant i++ in there, not studentArray++. Anyway, there would theoretically be an advantage toward the latter, but I doubt you'd ever see it. Just stick with the simple approach and do the first.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you're asking about C# / .NET.  The SelectNodes() call will be made once, and then the enumerator will be retrieved from the return value (which implements IEnumerable).  That enumerator is what is used during the loop, no subsequent calls to SelectNodes() are necessary.